# Are these two statements on limits equivalent?

Tags: real-analysis

> For some real valued function $f$, $\lim\limits_{x \to c}f(x) =L$ is equivalent to saying for any real sequence ${x_n}$, if $x_n$ converges to $c$, then $f(x_n)$ converges to $L$.

---

If this statement is true, I want to prove it using epsilon delta definition. For the latter statement, we know, $\forall \epsilon >0, \exists N \in \mathbb{N}$ so that $\forall n>N$ we have $0<|x_n-c|< \epsilon$. Now this should imply $f(x_n) \to L$ How do I show it?

Comment: No, it's not equivalent

Comment: @Andrew Can you provide a counterexample please.

Comment: For delta-epsilon, you don't want $0<|x_n-c|$; it's OK if $x_n=c$ for some (or even all) $n$. $|x_n-c|<\epsilon$ is all you need/want.

Comment: @GerryMyerson $c$ itself may or may not be in the domain of $f$ in this case

Comment: @Andrew i found this statement in one of the answers here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2967382/1215260

Comment: See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1992204/precise-proof-of-equivalence-of-two-definitions-of-limit-of-a-function

Answer (score 0):

Consider:
$$ f(x)= \begin{cases} 1 \quad & \text{if $x\neq 0$}\\ 0 \quad & \text{if $x =0$} \end{cases}$$
Consider  also $x_n =0$ for all $n$. Then $x_n\to 0$, and $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) =1$, but $f(x_n) = 0\,\, \forall$ $n$ and hence $f(x_n) \not \to 1$.

As pointed out in the comments, if you keep $c$ outside the range of the sequence, then the equivalence holds as proved in one of the links mentioned. Following is the equivalence:

> Suppose $f(x)$ is a real valued function. Then $\lim\limits_{x\to c} f(x) = L$ if and only if for every sequence $\{x_n\}$ with $x_n\neq c$, for all $n$, we have $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty} f(x_n) = L$,  whenever $x_n\to c$.